# Incorrectly rendered Markdown while editing user profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

While editing my 'About Me' I see this:

[image: about me]

As you can see in the live preview it correctly renders the `[tag:` stuff. But in the actual profile it doesn't:

[image: profile]

Can we fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have at least 10 reputation for links to render in your profile. That includes the tag links.